# How to check NsUserDefaults from launch screen in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in iOS application development. In my application I have a launch screen,login page and a home page. The launch screen is in separate storyboard and I want to check `NSUserDefaults` from launch screen to decide the user already logged in or not or how to check `NSUserDefaults` to bypass login screen to home screen.

Comment: from appdelegate you can manage this , and to decide which screen you want to show as first screen

Comment: You cannot do it in launch screen. But you can do it in app delegate inside of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

Comment: you cannot run a single letter of code while the iOS shows your lunch-screen, you can check whether the user logged in after the lunch is finished – maybe in your first view controller's or the root view controller's implementation.

Comment: @holex Actually the launch screen is shown until your code in application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) is finished.

Comment: @holex , it may be as am i still exploring iOS but as per requirement , i think he should check in appdelegate or may need to create a different viewcontroller where he can check that .

Comment: @RustamG, technically you are right, I used the wrong terminology there (not _cannot_ but _must not_ is the correct one) as I just said, the app-delegate is not for doing advanced job on controller-layer (however developers lustfully enjoy to overwhelm the `-application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method's body); it is only supposed loading the key window with a root-view-controller only – the root-view-controller is the first place when such task should be considered to be commit; not in the app-delegate.

Comment: @holex this is a good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If with launch screen you mean the a storyboard that is displayed while the app is starting then you are out of luck.

Since your app is starting, no code is run and you can not launch anything. You will have to do this is `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: Try to write `sleep(10)` inside of your App's delegate application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and see that your launch screen is displaying 10 seconds longer ;)

Comment: Never ever delay the startup of an app, this might crash your app as the watchdog might kill you app for taking to long to start.

Comment: It just demonstrates that you can run your own code while launch screen is showing.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the `NSUserDefaults` in `AppDelegate` Class, and also you need to access your ViewController from storyboard to show as home screen.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is the [application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) method in the `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // check whatever, so I can decide which ViewController should be the rootViewController

    return true
}
```

Comment: You say application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) but code snippet is for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 0):

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("login") == nil)
        {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "login")
        }
        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("login") == true)
        {

            do {
                let arr1 = try UserProfileDataHelper.find("1")
                if arr1?.Type == "Customer" {
                    currentUser = "Customer"
                    screenlaunch("MENU")
                }else{
                    currentUser = "Store"
                    screenlaunch("HOME")
                }

            } catch _{}


        }

         return true
    }

 func screenlaunch(str : String )
    {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(str)
            let navigationController :UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
            navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
            window!.rootViewController = nil
            window!.rootViewController = navigationController
            window?.makeKeyWindow()

    }
```